# printing, splitting, and replacing in lists

Tags: python, list, random, replace, split

I'm trying to make a quiz using a questions file, and a choice between two answer files. I am going to have the user choose between printing all questions and answers, or just a few randomly generated ones. My problem is that I am having trouble getting it to display as intended. I need for it to display like:

```
1. how many... etc.
a.answer
b.answer 
c.answer
d.answer
e.none of the above
```

but I can't get the output right. the text files consists of the answers placed like this:

```
C,3,4,5,6
A,4O,30,20,10
E,65,245,456,756
```

so I have replaced the commas with spaces, and have been succesful displaying them as a row rather than one line by using \n in place of spaces.. but it won't work as some answers are more than one word. I also need to remove the letter before the answers (it's the correct answer) and place this into a list, and I'm really unsure of how to do this.

```
import random


def main():
    print("Welcome to the Garbology Quiz \n")

    quizfilecheck = input("First off, what is the quiz file name? ")
    while quizfilecheck != "questions.txt":
          quizfilecheck = input("File not found.. what is the correct quiz file name? ")

    answerfilecheck = input("And now what answer file are you using? ")
    while answerfilecheck != "american-answers.txt" and answerfilecheck != "metric-answers.txt":
      answerfilecheck = input("File not found.. please enter the correct answer file name. ")


    questionList = getData()
    answerList = getFormat()
    inputanswers = printinputanswers(questionList,answerList)





def getData():
   with open("questions.txt") as questionFile:
        questionList = questionFile.readlines()

   return questionList

def getFormat():

   formatchoice = input("\n Would you like the answers printed in metric or american format? (m or a): ")
   formatchoice = formatchoice.lower()

   while formatchoice != "a" and formatchoice != "m":
      formatchoice = input("Invalid input, please enter a correct value (m or a): ")
      formatchoice = formatchoice.lower()

   if formatchoice == "a":
      answerPath = "american-answers.txt"
   else:
      answerPath = "metric-answers.txt"

   with open(answerPath) as answerFile:
      answerList = answerFile.readlines()



      return answerList

def printAllanswers(questionList,answerList):
   for i in range(0,len(questionList)):
      print(questionList[i])
      print(''.join(map(str,answerList[i].replace(',',' ').replace(' ','\n'))))
      allanswers = printAllanswers(questionList,answerList)

def printinputanswers(questionList,answerList):

   numofquestions = input(" How many questions do you want to print? ")
   if numofquestions.isdigit():
      numofquestions = int(numofquestions)
      for i in range(0,numofquestions):
         randomnum = random.randint(0,len(questionList))
         print (questionList[randomnum])
         print(''.join(map(str,answerList[randomnum].replace(',',' ').replace(' ',' '))))




main()
```

## ***********output  and i know I haven't called printallanswers() yet, I'm going to after I have the correct output working

```
First off, what is the quiz file name? questions.txt
And now what answer file are you using? metric-answers.txt

 Would you like the answers printed in metric or american format? (m or a): m
 How many questions do you want to print? 4
If every country consumed and threw away at the rate Americans do, how many planets' worth of resources would be required to meet the demand?

C 3 4 5 6

If every country consumed and threw away at the rate Americans do, how many planets' worth of resources would be required to meet the demand?

C 3 4 5 6

America is home to 4 percent of the world's children. What percentage of the world's toys do Americans buy and throw away?

A 4O 30 20 10

How many nonrecyclable Styrofoam cups do Americans throw away in a year?

D 5 billion 10 billion 15 billion 25 billion
```

#### code

```
def printsingleanswer(questionList,answerList):
   randomnum = random.randint(0,len(questionList))
   chars1= string.ascii_lowercase
   answers=answerList[randomnum].split(',')[1:] #removes the answer letter
   answers.append('none of the above')
   print ('\n'.join(chars1[i]+'. '+answers[i] for i in range(len(answers))))
```

## output

```
 Would you like the answers printed in metric or american format? (m or a): m
a. 5 billion
b. 10 billion
c. 15 billion
d. 25 billion

e. none of the above
```

## It's adding a new line before every "e" choice, is there a way to keep it grouped together like the first four choices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For answer sets that do not have commas, how about:

```
 import string
 chars1= string.ascii_lowercase
 answers=answerList[randomnum].strip().split(',')[1:] #removes the answer letter
 answers.append('none of the above')
 print '\n'.join(chars1[i]+'. '+answers[i] for i in range(len(answers)))
```

The statement:

```
 chars1[i]+'. '+answers[i],
```

adds a character to the beginning of each answer, and as string.ascii_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' this will give a alphabetic character to every answer starting with 'a'.

If there are commas then you have to store the file as a full csv and use the csv module to load the file and then rather than using a split as in the code above, you just use each row from the extracted csv.

Comment: what exactly does the import string and string.ascii_lowercase do? Just so I don't do it blindly.

Comment: string is a module with a lot of string related methods, but I am mostly just using it as it has a list of lower case characters.

string.ascii_lowercase is exactly that it equals: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' which let this work for questions with up to 25 answers (plus 'none of the above')

Comment: Unless i misunderstand your question, I believe that this is doing just that, the statement: chars1[i]+'. '+answers[i], adds a character to the beginning of each answer. Sorry that was clearly badly explained ill add this above

Comment: thank you so much, I'll try to make sure I implement this successfully. and I didn't see the full response in that comment, it was just a misunderstanding.

Comment: hmm, it's adding a new line before each "none of the above"

Comment: is that not what it was supposed to do? Sorry maybe i misunderstood?

Comment: ill post the output, one second

Comment: I didn't explain well enough, it's adding a blank new line before each none of the above answer

Comment: Sorry i now understand, it is because there are still new line characters at the end of each of the rows, i tested it on a pasted example see answer for fix

Comment: worked like a charm, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Gotta learn somewhere though.

Comment: I'm having some trouble trying to print every question at once, The randomly generated questions are working fine though